# Can you take any symplectic 2-form into canonical form via a coordinate transformation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism

Let's say we have a system with Hamilton equations

\begin{equation}
\dot{Y}^A = \Omega^{AB}H_{,B}
\end{equation}
where the coordinates are

\begin{equation}
Y^A=\big(q^i,p_j\big)
\end{equation}
where $i=1,\dots,N$ and $j=1,\dots,N$, $A=1\dots, 2N$, $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system and $\Omega$ is a symplectic 2-form, but not the canonical one, which is $\Omega_0 = \begin{bmatrix}0&\mathbb{I}_{N\times N}\\-\mathbb{I}_{N\times N}&0 \end{bmatrix}$

The question is: **Can we find new coordinates $Z^A$ (and probably new hamiltonian $K$) such that the equations of motion are written in the canonical form**

\begin{equation}
\dot{Z}^A=\Omega_0 ^{AB}K_{,B}
\end{equation}
**and if so, are there any conditions on $\Omega$ for it to happen? Is there a way to obtain such coordinate transformation?**

Comment: I guess Darboux's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem is what you are looking for. However, this only works locally

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem

Comment: Thanks! Are there conditions for it to work globally?

Comment: OP seems to have already asked about a **global** Darboux theorem on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3716083/11127